# Section ring $R(X,D)$ of $D$ is finitely generated if $\kappa (X,D) \leq 1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, algebraic-surfaces, minimal-model-program

In the remark on the bottom of page 5 of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0764444297888969) paper, the author states that

> It is  well-known fact that the algebra of a Divisor $D$ with $\kappa (X,D) \leq 1$ is finitely generated over $k$. In fact, by the Iitaka fibration, there exists a variety $Y$ of dimension $\kappa(X, D)$, and divisor $D'$ on $Y$ such that $R(X,D) \cong R(Y,D')$.

Assume $X$ to be a complete normal algebraic variety.

Can anyone give a reference for this well-known fact, or elucidate the "$\cong$" in his brief explanation? Of particular interest to me is the case with $X$ a surface and $\kappa(D)=1$.

Comment: I recommend that you contact the authors of that paper.  Anyway, it appears that the isomorphism, interpreted *strictly*, is false.  There are *Halphen surfaces*, cf. the excellent answer of Polizzi and comment of Loughran to the following MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283609/a-pencil-with-exactly-one-multiple-fibre/283661#comment700300_283661  In this case, the divisor class $D=-K_X$ has the property that for some integer $m>0$, the subring $R(X,mD)$ is isomorphic to $R(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(1))$.  Since $m$ is strictly larger than $1$, $R(X,D)$ is not $\cong R(Y,D')$.

Comment: If you read the introduction to that paper, I believe that the authors are implicitly allowing to replace the divisor $D$ by a positive integer multiple before constructing an isomorphism with $R(Y,D')$.  That would explain the claim that there always exists a curve $Y$ and an ample divisor $D'$ such that $R(X,D)\cong R(Y,D')$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Dear Jason, in my particular case (cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287146/map-associated-to-linear-system-onto-curve-is-morphism), a positive integer multiple would be fine. Could you explain why that explains the isomorphism?

(Accidentally hit enter earlier.)

Comment: For every linear system $(\mathcal{L},V)$ on $X$, there exists a normal projective variety $Y$, there exists an ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ on $Y$, and there exists a finite morphism from a normal variety, $\nu:\widetilde{X}\to X\times Y$, such that (i) the projection $p=\text{pr}_X\circ \nu:\widetilde{X}\to X$ is projective and birational, (ii) the  morphism $q=\text{pr}_Y\circ \nu:\widetilde{X}\to Y$ is a contraction, and (iii) there is a morphism $\phi:q^*\mathcal{A}\to p^*\mathcal{L}$ such that $p^*V$ is contained in the image of $H^0(Y,\mathcal{A})$ . . .

Comment: . . . For a fixed $\mathcal{M}$ on $X$, let $(\mathcal{M}^{\otimes m},V),$ $m\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, be such that $Y$ has maximal dimension.  For every $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, for every $s\in H^0(X,\mathcal{M}^{\otimes n})$, for the linear system $(\mathcal{M}^{\otimes mn},V')$ spanned by $V^n$ and $s^m$, for the associated contraction $\nu':\widetilde{X}'\to Y'$, there is a unique contraction $r:Y'\dashrightarrow Y$ and $\psi:r^*\mathcal{A}^{\otimes n} \to \mathcal{A}'$ such that $\phi^n$ factors through $\psi$. If $Y$ and $Y'$ have dimension $1$, then $r$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for the effort. I do agree that we can take the Iitaka fibration associated to our linear system, and $Y$ will be of dimension $1$ in my case. But I am afraid I don't follow the rest. In particular I don't see the point of the second post. What does some section from some $\mathscr M$, or the $r$, have to do with the isomorphism of the section rings?

Comment: The point of the second post is the final line.  Every contraction between normal, projective curves is automatically an isomorphism.  If that confuses you, I advise you to read about the valuative criterion of properness and Zariski's Main Theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. I am aware of Zariski's Main Theorem. I just remembered that $Y=\text{Proj}R$, and now I think I understand it. If it turns out that I don't I will attempt to get your attention once more via the comment section.